# How can I avoid over usage of ViewBag

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this project I'm working on. In the index view I have to display a lot of data that are probably not related. Currently my index action in the controller is looking totally messed up as I can say I've done it in a very amateurish way. I've read a lot about usage of ViewBag and some even say one should avoid using it totally and use a ViewModel instead. I've been implementing ViewModel and I understand the usefulness and I appreciate it. However in this project I don't know how to fashion my request into one view model because I'm querying some models that are not related so I can't start using join statements. See code below

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

    var db = new ApplicationDbContext();    
    var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(db));
    var CurrentUser = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
  /*******counts of loans*******/
    var PendingCounts = db.Transaction.Where(t => t.Status.Status == "Pending" && t.AgentId == CurrentUser.SalesAgent.AgentId).Count();
    var DeclinedCounts = db.Transaction.Where(t => t.Status.Status == "Declined" && t.AgentId == CurrentUser.SalesAgent.AgentId).Count();
    var ApprovedCounts = db.Transaction.Where(t => t.Status.Status == "Approved" && t.AgentId == CurrentUser.SalesAgent.AgentId).Count();   
    ViewBag.PendingCounts = PendingCounts;
    ViewBag.DeclinedCounts = DeclinedCounts;
    ViewBag.ApprovedCounts = ApprovedCounts;   
    /***Percentage of pending, approved and declined loans in counts******/
    decimal PendingCount = (decimal)PendingCounts;
    decimal DeclinedCount = (decimal)DeclinedCounts;
    decimal ApprovedCount = (decimal)ApprovedCounts;    
    decimal sum = PendingCount + DeclinedCount + ApprovedCount;    
    decimal PendingPercent = (PendingCount / sum) * 100;
    decimal DeclinedPercent = (DeclinedCount / sum) * 100;
    decimal ApprovedPercent = (ApprovedCount / sum) * 100;   
    ViewBag.PendingPercent = PendingPercent;
    ViewBag.DeclinedPercent = DeclinedPercent;
    ViewBag.ApprovedPercent = ApprovedPercent;    
    /****Value of loans******/
    //select SUM(AmountRequested) as totalPending from Transactions where StatusId = 1;     
    var ValuePending = db.Transaction.Where(t => t.AgentId == CurrentUser.SalesAgent.AgentId && t.Status.Status == "Pending").Select(t => (decimal?)t.AmountRequested).Sum() ?? 0;
    var ValueApproved = db.Transaction.Where(t => t.AgentId == CurrentUser.SalesAgent.AgentId && t.Status.Status == "Approved").Select(t => (decimal?)t.AmountApproved).Sum() ?? 0;
    var ValueDeclined = db.Transaction.Where(t => t.AgentId == CurrentUser.SalesAgent.AgentId && t.Status.Status == "Declined").Select(t => (decimal?)t.AmountRequested).Sum() ?? 0;  
    ViewBag.ValuePending = ValuePending;
    ViewBag.ValueApproved = ValueApproved;
    ViewBag.ValueDeclined = ValueDeclined;   
    var thisDate = DateTime.Now;
    var starting = new DateTime(thisDate.Year, thisDate.Month, 1);
    var ending = starting.AddMonths(1);
    var SpecifiedTotal = (from t in db.Transaction
                          where t.AgentId == CurrentUser.SalesAgent.AgentId
                          && t.Status.Status == "Approved"
                          && t.DateApproved >= starting && t.DateApproved < ending
                          select (decimal?)t.AmountApproved).Sum() ?? 0;

    var MonthlyTarget = db.SalesAgent.Where(t => t.AgentId == CurrentUser.SalesAgent.AgentId).Select(t => (decimal)t.MonthlyTarget).FirstOrDefault();
    var today = DateTime.Now;
    var year = DateTime.Now.Year;
    var month = DateTime.Now.Month;
    var day = DateTime.Now.Day;
    var NoOfDays = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);

    var start = today;
    var stop = new DateTime(year, month, NoOfDays);

    int WorkingDaysLeft = GetNumberOfWorkingDays(start, stop);
    decimal RunRate = Math.Round((MonthlyTarget - SpecifiedTotal) / WorkingDaysLeft, 2);
    ViewBag.RunRate = RunRate.ToString("N0");
    /***Get initials of current user*///
    var firstname = db.SalesAgent.Where(s => s.AgentId == CurrentUser.SalesAgent.AgentId).Select(s => s.AgentFirstName.Substring(0, 1)).SingleOrDefault();
    var lastname = db.SalesAgent.Where(s => s.AgentId == CurrentUser.SalesAgent.AgentId).Select(s => s.AgentLastName.Substring(0, 1)).SingleOrDefault();
    //ViewBag.firstnameletter = firstnameletter;
    //ViewBag.lastnameletter = lastnameletter;
    return View();
}
```

as you can see I've stuffed a lot of data into the ViewBag because I need to show it in my view for example my view looks like this

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div class="imagecircle">
    @ViewBag.firstnameletter @ViewBag.lastnameletter
</div>

<div class="row searchForm">
    <form action="/Home/Index" method="post">

        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <label>Start</label>
            <input type="date" class="StartDate form-control" name="StartDate" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <label>End</label>
            <input type="date" class="EndDate form-control" name="EndDate" />
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Search" class="submit btn btn-default " />

    </form>
</div>

<div class="row header">
    <div class="col-lg-3 section">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <h4><span class="countNumber">@ViewBag.PendingCounts</span></h4> Transaction(s) Pending
                <h4> <span class="countNumber">@ViewBag.PendingPercent</span>%</h4> Transaction(s) Pending
                <h4><span class="countNumber">@ViewBag.ValuePending</span></h4> in value so far
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 countHeader">
                <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
               <h5>Pending</h5> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 section">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8">

                <h4><span class="countNumber">@ViewBag.ApprovedCounts</span></h4> Transaction(s) Approved
                <h4><span class="countNumber">@ViewBag.ApprovedPercent</span>%</h4> Transaction(s) Approved
                <h4><span class="countNumber">@ViewBag.ValueApproved</span></h4> in value so far

            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 countHeader">
                <i class="fa fa-check-circle-o"></i>
                <h5>Approved</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 section">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <h4><span class="countNumber">@ViewBag.DeclinedCounts</span></h4> Transaction(s) Declined
                <h4><span class="countNumber">@ViewBag.DeclinedPercent</span>%</h4> Transaction(s) Declined
                <h4><span class="countNumber">@ViewBag.ValueDeclined</span></h4> in value so far
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 countHeader">
                <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
                <h5>Declined</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 RunRate">
      <p><sup><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i></sup>Run Rate = &#8358 @ViewBag.RunRate</p> 
        <p>This is the amount you should get disbursed daily in order to meet your target this month.</p> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Because I needed to perform lots of calculations on the results of my query I find it difficult to use a ViewModel hence I'm stuck with ViewBag. I know this is far from professional as it doesn't look clean and smooth.  I think I will try to refactor those single query where I'm expecting a single result into methods, but what improvement do you think I need to do on the code above? Do help with code examples.

Comment: _"i find it difficult to use a ViewModel"_ - well, you need a viewmodel.

Comment: Honestly, I agree with @CodeCaster, I'd even add that you need to think about the sheer size of that `Index()` action and how maintainable that is in it's current shape. Have a think about how you're designing your domain and your solution accordingly.

Comment: **Why** do you find it difficult to use a view model? They're specifically created to solve the problem you have. You appear to be confusing domain models with view models. View models can contain within them multiple domain models, and should just be thought of as a mechanism to communicate the necessary data from the controller to the view.

Comment: "Because i needed to perform lots of calculations on the results of my query i find it difficult to use a ViewModel."

This makes no sense to me. Create a new class called "IndexViewModel" find and replace ViewBag with "IndexViewModel" let VS add all the missing properties. And you're done. 

Saying, "I find it difficult to use a ViewModel" is like saying, "I know what the right answer is, but I don't want to do it." :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on code review stack exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ViewModels store the presentation logic needed for a view.

Although I question why many of the calculations are not part of the models themselves I leave it as a refactoring exercise to remove the business logic from the viewmodel into the model.

Additionally I leave refactoring the view to use the viewmodel as an exercise of the reader.

Here is an example of a viewmodel for your stuff:

```
public class TransactionViewModel
{
    public TransactionViewModel(
        List<Transaction> transactions,
        SalesAgent salesAgent)
    {
        Transactions = transactions;
        SalesAgent = salesAgent;
    }

    public List<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }

    public SalesAgent SalesAgent { get; set; }

    public decimal MonthlyTarget
    {
        get { return (decimal) SalesAgent.MonthlyTarget; }
    }

    public string SalesAgentInitials
    {
        get
        {
            return
                string.Format(
                    "{0}.{1}.",
                    SalesAgent.FirstName.First(),
                    SalesAgent.LastName.First());
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<Transaction> ApprovedTransactions
    {
        get { return Transactions.Where(t => t.Status.Status == "Approved"); }
    }

    public IEnumerable<Transaction> PendingTransactions
    {
        get { return Transactions.Where(t => t.Status.Status == "Pending"); }
    }

    public IEnumerable<Transaction> DeclinedTransactions
    {
        get { return Transactions.Where(t => t.Status.Status == "Declined"); }
    }

    public int ApprovedCount
    {
        get { ApprovedTransactions.Count(); }
    }

    public int PendingCount
    {
        get { PendingTransactions.Count(); }
    }

    public int DeclinedCount
    {
        get { DeclinedTransactions.Count(); }
    }

    public int TotalCount
    {
        get { return Transactions.Count; }
    }

    public decimal ApprovedPercent
    {
        get { return (decimal) ApprovedCount / TotalCount }
    }

    public decimal PendingPercent
    {
        get { return (decimal) PendingCount / TotalCount }
    }

    public decimal DeclinedPercent
    {
        get { return (decimal) DeclinedCount / TotalCount }
    }

    public decimal ApprovedValue
    {
        get { return ApprovedTransactions.Select(t => (decimal?)t.AmountRequested).Sum() ?? 0; }
    }

    public decimal PendingValue
    {
        get { return PendingTransactions.Select(t => (decimal?)t.AmountRequested).Sum() ?? 0; }
    }

    public decimal DeclinedValue
    {
        get { return DeclinedTransactions.Select(t => (decimal?)t.AmountRequested).Sum() ?? 0; }
    }

    public DateTime StartMonth
    {
        get { return new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, 1); }
    }

    public DateTime EndMonth
    {
        get { return StartMonth.AddMonths(1); }
    }

    public int DaysInMonth
    {
        get { return (EndMonth - StartMonth).Days; }
    }

    public int WorkingDaysLeftInMonth
    {
        get
        {
            Enumerable
                .Range(DateTime.Today.Day, DaysInMonth)
                .Select(d => new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, d))
                .Count(date =>
                    date.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday &&
                    date.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday);
        }
    }

    public decimal SpecifiedTotal
    {
        get
        {
            return
                ApprovedTransactions
                    .Where(t => t.DateApproved >= StartMonth && t.DateApproved < EndMonth)
                    .Select(t => (decimal?) t.AmountApproved)
                    .Sum() ?? 0;
        }
    }

    public decimal RunRate
    {
        get { return Math.Round((MonthlyTarget - SpecifiedTotal) / WorkingDaysLeftInMonth, 2); }
    }

    public string RunRateFormat
    {
        get { return RunRate.ToString("N0"); }
    }
}
```

This simplifies the action:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var db = new ApplicationDbContext();    
    var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(db));
    var CurrentUser = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());

    var loans =
        db.Transaction
          .Where(t =>
              t.AgentId == CurrentUser.SalesAgent.AgentId)
          .ToList();

    var salesAgent = 
        db.SalesAgent
          .FirstOrDefault(s => s.AgentId == CurrentUser.SalesAgent.AgentId);

    var viewModel = new TransactionViewModel(loans, salesAgent)

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Comment: That made my day, currently striving to understand all